# NetBeans debug session from REST client

Tags: php, api, debugging, rest, netbeans

I frequently use the NetBeans debugger to step through my PHP applications. However, I also want to use the debugger when working on things that do not run in a web browser, per se (specifically a REST API).

Does anybody know how to start a NetBeans debugger session that will allow me to use my REST client as the "browser"?

Misc. info: Mac OS X, CocoaRestClient, NetBeans 7.1.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need several things:

- activate remote debugging in your server config (xdebug.remote_enable = 1 in php.ini then restart server)
- generate a Xdebug IDE key from netbeans (I don't know how to do this with netbeans, but it won't be hard to find)
- ensure that Neatbeans is listening the the DBGP port (usually 9000)
- add a request parameter in each request sent with your client with:

name : XDEBUG_SESSION_START

value : [your IDE key]

For me, works like a charm with PHPStorm.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. The Xdebug IDE key is simply netbeans-xdebug, for anyone else who is looking. Also remember that the XDEBUG_SESSION_START should be in the request body, not in headers (something I was doing for a while).

Answer (score 0):

To help with PHPStorm's recent REST Client - here's a screenshot of the appropriate settings. Make sure to, in settings, change the DBGP listening port from 9001 to 9000 if not set already. Thanks for the answer!

http://screencast.com/t/WsZzApBORssx